# PHP + Code Igniter Timecode Calculation Logic Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, logic

I have what I suspect to be a logic problem with an algorithm I am using to work with Video timecode in PHP. All help is appreciated.

**The Objective**

Well basically I want to work with timecode and perform calculations

For those not familiar with timecode it looks like this

> *01:10:58:12 or HH:MM:SS:FF 'AKA' HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS:FRAMES*

I have used the script from [HERE](http://chxo.com/scripts/pTCcalc.php/?source) to help me with working with this format.

**The Problem**

Now can i just say that this script works!!! Timecode calculations (in this case additions) are being performed correctly. However this script continually throws the following errors, yet still produces the correct output when I try and do the following calculation

> 00:01:26:00 + 00:02:00:12

The errors from this calculation are shown below

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: key
>
> Filename: staff/tools.php
>
> Line Number: 169
>
> **A PHP Error was
>   encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: key
>
> Filename: staff/tools.php
>
> Line Number: 169

Line Number 169 is in the *parseInput()* function

```
// feed it into the tc array
$i=0;
foreach ($tc AS $key=>$value) {
    if ( is_numeric($array["$i"]) ) {
        $tc["$key"]= $array["$i"];
        if ($tc["$key"] < 10 && $tc["$key"] > 0 && strlen($tc['key'])==1 ) $tc["$key"]= "0".$tc["$key"];
        }
    $i++;
    }

return $tc;
```

Now I should also mention that the number of times the above error is thrown depends on what I am calculating

> 00:00:00:00 + 00:00:00:00

returns no errors.

> 01:01:01:01 + 02:02:02:02

produces 8 of the above errors.

---

For your reference, here is the code in it's entirety

```
function add_cue_sheet_clips_process()
{

$sheetID = $_POST['sheet_id'];
$clipName = $_POST['clip_name'];
$tcIn = $_POST['tc_in'];
$tcOut = $_POST['tc_out'];

// string $input
// returns an associative array of hours, minutes, seconds, and frames
//
function parseInput ($input) {
// timecode should look something like hh:mm:ss;ff
// allowed separators are : ; . ,
// values may be single or double digits
// hours are least-significant -- 5.4 == 00:00:05;04
$tc= array("frames"=>"00", "seconds"=>"00", "minutes"=>"00", "hours"=>"00");
$punct= array(":", ";", ".", ",");

// too big? too small?
$input= trim($input);
if (strlen($input)>11 || $input=="") {
    // invalid input, too long -- bzzt
    return $tc;
    }

// normalize punctuation
$input= str_replace( $punct, ":", $input);

// blow it up and reverse it so frames come first
$array= explode(":", $input);
$array= array_reverse($array);

// feed it into the tc array
$i=0;
foreach ($tc AS $key=>$value) {
    if ( is_numeric($array["$i"]) ) {
        $tc["$key"]= $array["$i"];
        if ($tc["$key"] < 10 && $tc["$key"] > 0 && strlen($tc['key'])==1 ) $tc["$key"]= "0".$tc["$key"];
        }
    $i++;
    }

return $tc;
}

// array $tc
// returns a float number of seconds
//
function tcToSec($tc) {
    $wholeseconds= ($tc['hours']*3600) + ($tc['minutes'] * 60) + ($tc['seconds']);
    $partseconds= ( $tc['frames']  / 25 );
    $seconds= $wholeseconds + $partseconds;
    return $seconds;
    }

// float $seconds
// bool $subtract
// returns a timecode array
//
function secToTc ($seconds=0, $subtract=0) {
    $tc= array("frames"=>"00", "seconds"=>"00", "minutes"=>"00", "hours"=>"00");

    $partseconds= fmod($seconds, 1);
    $wholeseconds= $seconds - $partseconds;

    // frames
    if ($subtract==1) $tc['frames']= floor( $partseconds * 25 );
    else $tc['frames']= floor( $partseconds * 25 );

    // hours
    $tc['hours']= floor( $wholeseconds / 3600 );
    $minsec= ($wholeseconds - ($tc['hours'] * 3600));

    // minutes
    $tc['minutes']= floor( $minsec / 60 );

    // seconds
    $tc['seconds']= ( $minsec - ($tc['minutes'] * 60) );

    // padding
    foreach ( $tc AS $key=>$value ) {
        if ($value > 0 && $value < 10) $tc["$key"]= "0".$value;
        if ($value=="0") $tc["$key"]= "00";
        }
    return $tc;
    }

// array $tc
// returns string of well-formed timecode
//
function tcToString (&$tc) {
    return $tc['hours'].":".$tc['minutes'].":".$tc['seconds'].";".$tc['frames'];
    }


$timecodeIN = parseInput($tcIn);
$timecodeOUT = parseInput($tcOut); 

// normalized inputs...
$tc1 = tcToString($timecodeIN);
$tc2 = tcToString($timecodeOUT);

// get seconds
$seconds1 = tcToSec($timecodeIN);
$seconds2 = tcToSec($timecodeOUT);

$result = $seconds1 + $seconds2;

$timecode3 = secToTc($result, 0);
$timecodeDUR = tcToString($timecode3);

$clipArray = array('clip_name' => $clipName, 'tc_in' => $tcIn, 'tc_out' => $tcOut, 'tc_duration' => $timecodeDUR);

$this->db->insert('tools_cue_sheets_clips', $clipArray);

redirect('staff/tools/add_cue_sheet_clips/'.$sheetID);
}
```

---

I hope this is enough information for someone to help me get on top of this, I would be extremely greatful.

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOTICE Errors are usually minor, Heres an example

```
if($unamedVaraible){/.../} //Notince: undefined variable

if(isset($unamedVaraible)){/..../} //no error as its checking correctly for the purpose
```

of you done

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ///Show all errors but E_NOTICE
```

you will be able to supress these errors.

You'll find the error_reporting() function located at the top of your main index.php file.